# how to append data to a variable and make it clickable hyperlink

Tags: python

```
RC_Fixed = '12345'
print RC_Fixed
```

I want to change RC_Fixed in such a way that it is a clickable link to "http://database.com/RC/12345",so basically
for any value in RC_Fixed ,i want to append "http://database.com/RC/" and make it a clickable hyperlink,please
suggest how this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output a HTML link

```
RC_Fixed = '12345'
link = "http://database.com/RC/" + RC_Fixed
print "<a href='" + link + "'>" + RC_fixed + "</a>"
```